# Multiple DateTime range MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
---------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+
| id      | user_id | start_date_time   | end_date_time      |
+---------+---------+-------------------+--------------------+
|       1 |      11 |2019-11-17 20:10:00|2019-11-17 21:05:00 |
|       2 |      11 |2019-11-17 20:18:00|2019-11-17 20:35:00 |
|       3 |      11 |2019-11-17 20:32:00|2019-11-17 21:18:00 |
|       4 |      11 |2019-11-17 20:40:00|2019-11-17 20:50:00 |
|       5 |      11 |2019-11-17 20:45:00|2019-11-17 21:20:00 |
|         |         |                   |                    |
+---------+---------+-------------------+--------------------+

Scenario 1 - If i query for all greater than '2019-11-17 20:18:00' I need to get all records.
Scenario 2 - If i query for all possible dates greater or equals '2019-11-17 21:18:00' It should return record 3 and 5.
```

For any given time it should look for Start_date_time and End_date_time where given time should be considered as start time and it should look for appropriate end_date_time and output the result.

In a nut shell input time should be taken as starting range and it should look for End_date_time and give me all values between.

How can i accomplish this?

i tried the following ways on db-fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bPk1CYioL6cVasStZKzQ4j/7

if i query all records from a given time eg(2019-11-17 20:18:00) the input should be taken as a start datetime of range and look for the most greatest end_date_time and give me the records between them. Example `2019-11-17 20:18:00` this input takes range between input as val1 of range `2019-11-17 20:18:00` to `2019-11-17 21:20:00` the highest end date and give me all records between. And if i query with input `2019-11-17 21:05:00` this should take start range val1 as `2019-11-17 21:05:00` and `2019-11-17 21:20:00` output 1,3,5 records.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. For example for `'2019-11-17 20:18:00'` why do you want row 3 in the results?

Comment: @forpas if i query all records from a given time eg(`2019-11-17 20:18:00`) the input should be taken as a start datetime of range and look for the most greatest end_date_time and give me the records between them. Example `2019-11-17 20:18:00` this input takes range between input as val1 of range `2019-11-17 20:18:00` to `2019-11-17 21:20:00` the highest end date and give me all records between. And if i query with input `2019-11-17 21:05:00` this should take start range val1 as `2019-11-17 21:05:00` and `2019-11-17 21:20:00` output 1,3,5 records. Hope i clarified the requirement.

Comment: Did you try `end_date_time >= '2019-11-17 20:18:00'` and `end_date_time >= '2019-11-17 21:18:00'` for the scenarios respectively. e.g. values of `start_date_time` has no sense for the scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement (with the results that you expect) is as simple as that:

```
select * 
from times
where ? <= end_date_time
```

Replace `?` with the datetime that you want to query.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=8363cc821516fc96149e615df98831ee).